# How to find gitlab version?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I have a gitlab backup which has data in the form of config, Data and logs.
As I am trying to restore the backup in my local host, I am unable to do it because I don't know the version of this Gitlab. The previous virtual machine where this gitlab was hosted has died. So is there any way, I can know the version of gitlab from this backup, I have recovered??

Comment: For GitLab backup with configs, it does not have a version tag. Though, a backup with only the config info and not the repo does not mean anything. And if you find your GitLab backups for repo(typically a tar file), it might have a version affixed in its name.